# A question on Cox-Processes (Markov-Modulated Poisson processes)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, hidden-markov-models

I´m trying to prove that a Markov-Modulated Poisson process could be seen as a 2-dimensional continuous time markov chain.

For this, I'm considering a two state markov chain $\{J(t) : t \geq 0\}$ with Q-matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha_1 & \alpha_1\\ \alpha_2 &-\alpha_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and two positive numbers $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.

Thereby, if $\{N(t) : t\geq 0\}$ is a cox-proccess with rate $\lambda(t) = \beta_{J(t)}$, then
$\{(N(t),J(t)) : t \geq 0\}$ is a two state markov chain.

I supuse that this result is true. Moreover, I think that $\{N(t) : t \geq 0\}$ is a two state markov chain with state space $E = \mathbb{N}_0 \times\{1,2\}$,* jump matrix given by
$$\Pi_{(i,j),(k,l)} = \begin{cases}
 \frac{\beta_{j}}{\alpha_j + \beta_{j}},& \text{ si } k = i+1 \text{ y } j = l. \\
 \frac{\alpha_j}{\alpha_j + \beta_{j}}, & \text{ si }k= i \text{ y } l \in\{1,2\}\setminus\{j\}.\\ 
 0, &\text{e.o.c}. \end{cases}$$
and $Q$-matrix given by
$$  Q_{(i,j),(k,l)} = \begin{cases}
 \beta_{j},& \text{ si } k = i+1 \text{ y } j = l. \\
 \alpha_j, & \text{ si }k= i \text{ y } l \in\{1,2\}\setminus\{j\}.\\
  -(\alpha_j + \beta_{j}), & \text{ si }k= i \text{ y } l = j.\\
 0, &\text{e.o.c}. 
\end{cases}$$
I've tried to prove this by using the arrival times of the cox process and the markov chain $J(t)$, but I havent achieve anithing up to now. So, I'll be very glad with any sugestion.

*Where $\mathbb{N}_0 = \{0,1,2,3,...\}$.

Comment: TL;DR. A Poisson process can only increase. This resticts considerably the Markov chains that could be your candidates.